# Gracefully handle power loss Raspbian on a Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian, boot, power, filesystem, shutdown

I recently installed a [Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/) running [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) for my folks. They live in a rural area and only have a 4G Modem with a limited data plan. The issue, is that every now and then there are power outages due to bad weather.

Is there a way I can configure the filesystem so it can handle ungraceful power downs when there's a power outage?

Comment: install a UPS that can interface with the RPi either by USB or serial connection ... run a UPS monitoring watchdog program

Comment: I also thought about using a power bank with USB ports. Apparently it can channel 1.0A which should be more than enough for the Pi Zero. However, a UPS sounds like a more robust solution. Thanks for the suggestion @jsotola

Comment: power bank is ok to use, but the RPi needs to detect a power outage so that it can perform a graceful shutdown ... not really sure how it would turn back on though .... i think that there may be some product available to do that

Comment: Does their 4G modem continues to function during a power outage? Are you trying to keep their service up, or just concerned about data corruption on the RPi SD card due to power outages?

Comment: Currently the 4G Modem is a USB stick that's not attached (yet) to the Pi. This means that if the power's down, there's no Internet. I was planning on connecting the 4G USB stick to the Pi via micro USB adapter, this way they'll have Internet along with ad-blocking capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (native) `ext4` filesystem is said to be robust with respect to power outages ([ref.](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/supported-and-recommended-file-systems-on-linux/)). I'd *guess* that file system corruption due to a shortcoming of `ext4` is less likely than random corruption of your SD card. If that's true, consider spending a bit more for a high-quality SD card & don't worry too much about tweaking the filesystem. Maintaining a good back-up of your SD card is a wise practice also.

There is at least one technique for making the FS more resistant to corruption: mount the drive using the `barrier` option ([see this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/403891/journaled-filesystems-and-power-failure)). I'm not sure the `barrier` option for mounting a drive is available in the Raspbian kernel - or if it's necessary in this case, but this is a possibility if you want to do some more research.

Comment: I'm not sure the `barrier` option is built into the Raspbian Kernel @Seamus. 
According to the Linux Kernel Archives  `ext4` [enables write barriers by default](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt). I checked `fstab` as well as the output of `mount` and did not see any barrier option for the root `/` filesystem; if it's enabled, I found no way of proving so. They only thing I can report is that at the time of this comment, we had 6 power outages and Pi Zero is running perfectly.

Comment: **Update**: I edited `fstab` and added the `barrier=1` option to `/`. After rebooting the system and calling `mount` it didn't show a `barrier` option. However, running the command `dmesg | grep barrier` yields that `/` has been mounted with `Opts: barrier=1`. So, apparently `barrier` is indeed built into the kernel `4.19.75+`.

Comment: @JuanMarco: That's very interesting! In the "hidden" comments to the answer I referenced, the author of that answer stated that `barrier` was built in & enabled by default on `ext4`. That's consistent with your findings in LKA. The only thing that occurs to me is this:  *Does `dmesg` report a default built into the kernel, or does it report the fact that an option has been set in `fstab`?* Ideally, it would do both, but experience suggests this may not be so. I feel this is a question worth of further research :) But it seems almost certain that enabling the option does no harm.

Comment: `dmesg` currently reports that the fs was "re-mounted" with `Opts: barrier=1`. This appeared after I enabled `barrier` option from within `fstab`. Before this, there were no other indications or defaults related to barrier (at least that I could find) from the `dmesg` output.

Comment: @JuanMarco: Yes, exactly... all I'm saying is that if `barrier` is a default in `ext4`, then `dmesg` might not report it.